# Javascript: Echo a Variable inside Curly brackets and Square brackets

Tags: javascript

Javascript array needs to replace the static values inside the square brackets[] and curly Brackets {}

```
console.log(my_array[0]); // This returns  x: 201.5,y: 136.5,z: 0

$('#superdiv').addSpice(function(super){
return $(document.createElement('span')).addClass('note').html(super.z);},              
[  {x: 0.3875, y: 0.3246, z: 4},  //Should be Array Value1
    {x: 0.57, y: 0.329, z: 2}     //Should be Array Value2
 ]);}
```

Right now everything inside the [] is static ... I have an array that has several values like the following and I want to fill the values into same manner ... but with the array my_array[0]="x: 0.3875, y: 0.3246, z: 4"; my_array[1]="x: 0.57, y: 0.329, z: 2";

Comment: exactly, what is the question?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. What are you trying to achieve? (And as a first step, I'd suggest a bit of code formatting so you can tell what's happening; right now it's a jumble.)

Comment: please delete the tags "square-bracket" and "curly-brackets", they have nothing in special with your question

Comment: Trying to explain the question better.

Right now everything inside the [] is static ... 
I have an array that has several values like the following and I want to fill the values into same manner ... but with the array
my_array[0]="x: 0.3875, y: 0.3246, z: 4";
my_array[1]="x: 0.57, y: 0.329, z: 2";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#superdiv').addSpice(function(super){
   return $(document.createElement('span')).addClass('note').html(super.z);},          
    [  {x: my_array[0].x, y: my_array[0].y, z: my_array[0].z},  //Should be Array Value1
       {x: my_array[1].x, y: my_array[1].y, z: my_array[1].z}     //Should be Array Value2
    ]);}
...
```

Something like that ?

Comment: @user1117644 Well that's another problem with the array initialization

Comment: I initialized it like so in php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">  var my_array=new Array(".$count.");"

then loop
array_push($my_array,  "'x: ".$product->x.",y: ".$product->y.",z: ".$product->z."';");

Comment: @user1117644 I think that's another matter that should have its own question.

Comment: I made the array properly so it works now. However the syntax you suggested does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want something like this?

```
var arrclone = my_array.splice(0).map(
                  function(obj){
                    var str = []; 
                    for (var l in obj){
                      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(l)){
                       str.push(l+': '+obj[l]);
                      }
                    }
                  return str.join(',');
               });
arrclone[0]; //=> ["x: 0.3875,y: 0.3246,z: 4"]
```

Comment: very strange output when I did that
0: x,1: :,2:  ,3: 2,4: 0,5: 1,6: .,7: 5,8: ,,9: y,10: :,11:  ,12: 1,13: 3,14: 6,15: 

still thanks for trying